# Time taken by GroupBy

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a huge table in MySql (more than 80 million tuples) for 30 days, on which I want to run `group by` query. I've already given the `index` to the column where I want to run `group by`
I would like to know whether processing each day (total 30) will be faster or processing just once for all the 30 days.
I'm using Python script for playing with the DB

EDIT : 
This the the query for 1 day (run 30 times, each time with next date):

```
 q1 =  Select date(time) Date,count(user_name) from users group by Date where date(time) = '2014-03-02';
```

and this is for all the 30 days (run just once):

```
q2 =  Select date(time) Date, count(user_name) from users group by Date
```

So, it all boils down to:
Whether q1 is more efficient (run 30 times) or q2 (run once)

Comment: 1. MySQL won't be able to use more that one index in query. 2. If your supposed index for `GROUP BY` is compound and in `WHERE` it's left-subset of columns of it, it will be used. 3. Please, show your exact structure, query & `EXPLAIN` plan

Comment: Neither your `WHERE` not `GROUP BY` will use index because MySQL won't be able to apply index for function-evaluated fields. So both queries will not use indexes - thus, first is better

Answer (score -1):

Obviously each day will be faster..
One day data is less than whole data and needs less space to perform group by operation on less data as group by is perform after fetching the one day data..

Thanks